# how to transform value of a column into multiple rows in python

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a table like this:

```
date              type          value
2021-02-03        a              150
2021-02-04        b              150
2021-02-05        c              150
```

I want to divide the `value` into three rows and create a new column called `category` which is filled by x, y, and z respectively.

The desired table is like this:

```
date              type          value      category
2021-02-03        a              50           x
2021-02-03        a              50           y
2021-02-03        a              50           z
2021-02-04        b              50           x
2021-02-04        b              50           y
2021-02-04        b              50           z
2021-02-05        c              50           x
2021-02-05        c              50           y
2021-02-05        c              50           z
```

how can I make it in python?

Answer (score 2):

If the data is really that specific I would suggest some approach with generators and `pd.DataFrame.explode()`.

```
# sample data
data = [
        {"date": "2021-02-03", "type": "a", "value": 150},
        {"date": "2021-02-04", "type": "b", "value": 150},
        {"date": "2021-02-05", "type": "c", "value": 150},
    ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# how much groups you are going to divide the columns "value" for
groups = 3
# this will create a list from the value integer, where each element in list is the exactly amount needed to explode afterwards, in this example [50, 50, 50]
df["value"] = df["value"].apply(lambda x: [x / groups for _ in range(groups)])
# explode the list into n rows 
df = df.explode("value", ignore_index=True)

# categories generator
def categories_generator():
    categories = ["x", "y", "z"]
    while True:
        for category in categories:
            yield category

c_gen = categories_generator()

# create a new columns from a pd.Series() where you iteract through the generator
df["category"] = pd.Series([next(c_gen) for _ in range(len(df))])
```

Answer (score 1):

The question required to replicate a row with three rows equal in `date` and `type` but different in `value`. The `value` should be partitioned into equal values for three categories. A quick solution can be:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

L = [
  ["2021-02-03", "a", 150],
  ["2021-02-04", "b", 150],
  ["2021-02-05", "c", 150],
]
header = ["date", "type", "value"]
df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=header)
print(df)

newData = [
  {**df.iloc[i].copy(), "value": df.iloc[i, 2] / 3.0, "category": cat}
  for cat in ["x", "y", "z"] # Loop on each category.
  for i in range(len(df)) # Loop on each row.
]
newDf = pd.DataFrame(newData, columns=header + ["category"])
# Sort the rows by date and category inplace.
newDf.sort_values(by=["date", "category"], inplace=True)
print(newDf)
```

The original records are:

```
         date type  value
0  2021-02-03    a    150
1  2021-02-04    b    150
2  2021-02-05    c    150
```

The output should be:

```
         date type  value category
0  2021-02-03    a   50.0        x
3  2021-02-03    a   50.0        y
6  2021-02-03    a   50.0        z
1  2021-02-04    b   50.0        x
4  2021-02-04    b   50.0        y
7  2021-02-04    b   50.0        z
2  2021-02-05    c   50.0        x
5  2021-02-05    c   50.0        y
8  2021-02-05    c   50.0        z
```

It is worth noting that, if it is required to increase the number of categories, the value `3.0` in `df.iloc[i, 2] / 3.0` should be modified. Also, if the question required the value to be an integer value, use `int(df.iloc[i, 2] / 3.0)` instead of `df.iloc[i, 2] / 3.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```py
# initialize the number of categories for each type
n = 3
# repeat df n times
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(n)]
# divide values in value column
df['value'] /= n
# insert category column
df['category'] = ['x','y','z'] * n
# reset the index to fix duplicate indices
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
out = df.assign(category='xyz', value=df.value.div(3))
out.category = out.category.apply(list)
out = out.explode('category')
print(out)
>>>
    date    type    value   category
0   2021-02-03  a   50.0    x
0   2021-02-03  a   50.0    y
0   2021-02-03  a   50.0    z
1   2021-02-04  b   50.0    x
1   2021-02-04  b   50.0    y
1   2021-02-04  b   50.0    z
2   2021-02-05  c   50.0    x
2   2021-02-05  c   50.0    y
2   2021-02-05  c   50.0    z
```